# How to open Appstore sandbox manage subscription sheet (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugin-purchase

I'm using cordova-plugin-purchase from j3k0 to implement IAP in my app. The plugin give a method called ***store.manageSubscriptions()*** which open subscriptions sheet in Appstore app. The problem is subscriptions sheet opened is not sandbox sheet, I want to open sandbox subscriptions sheet instead of the real sheet. Can I have some help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup test users as per [the manual](https://purchase.cordova.fovea.cc/discover/generalities-about-iap-technology#test-accounts)

> Test Accounts
> On both iOS and Android, you can create Test Users that
> do not pay for the purchases they make. We'll show you how to achieve
> this.